# GSSAPI: Error 0x80090311 returned by InitializeSecurityContext

Tags: c++, active-directory, kerberos

I need to set up an active directory authentication system using Kerberos. My `AcquireCredentialsHandleA` class looks as follows. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthn/acquirecredentialshandle--kerberos

```
SEC_WINNT_AUTH_IDENTITY AuthData, *pAuthData = NULL;
#ifdef UNICODE
    AuthData.Flags = SEC_WINNT_AUTH_IDENTITY_UNICODE;
#else
    AuthData.Flags = SEC_WINNT_AUTH_IDENTITY_ANSI;
#endif
    unsigned char username[200] = "user";
    unsigned char domain[200] = "domain.com";
    unsigned char password[100] = "secret";
    AuthData.User = &username[0]; //username
    AuthData.Domain = &domain[0]; //domain
    AuthData.Password = &password[0]; //password
    AuthData.UserLength = AuthData.User ? sizeof(AuthData.User) : 0;
    AuthData.DomainLength = AuthData.Domain ? sizeof(AuthData.Domain) : 0;
    AuthData.PasswordLength = AuthData.Password ? sizeof(AuthData.Password) : 0;

Status = g_pSSPI->AcquireCredentialsHandleA(
        NULL,                 // Name of principal   //pN       
        ppPackageInfo[2].Name,//"kerberos" Name of package 
        SECPKG_CRED_OUTBOUND, // Flags indicating use
        NULL,                 // Pointer to logon ID
        pAuthData, //NULL,    // Package specific data
        NULL,                 // Pointer to GetKey() func
        NULL,                 // Value to pass to GetKey()
        phCreds,              // (out) Cred Handle
        &tsExpiry
    );
```

This returns Success. However, when I call my `InitializeSecurityContextA`function it gives me 0x80090311 error which means `SEC_E_NO_AUTHENTICATING_AUTHORITY`. I have tried all sorts of possible domain name etc. When I do `ksetup` in the powershell it can generate ticket with same credentials. But the code always fails. Can anyone spot any problem here?

```
dwSSPIFlags = ISC_REQ_ALLOCATE_MEMORY | ISC_REQ_USE_SESSION_KEY | ISC_REQ_CONNECTION; // Not sure at all about them flags

    OutBuffers[0].pvBuffer = NULL;
    OutBuffers[0].BufferType = SECBUFFER_TOKEN; //2
    //OutBuffers[0].cbBuffer = 0;
    OutBuffers[0].cbBuffer = 7084;

    OutBuffer.cBuffers = 1;
    OutBuffer.pBuffers = OutBuffers;
    OutBuffer.ulVersion = SECBUFFER_VERSION; //0    
    Status = g_pSSPI->InitializeSecurityContextA
            (
                phCreds,
                fHaveCtxtHandle ? phContext : NULL,//phContext, can be NULL for the first call 
                server, 
                dwSSPIFlags,
                0,
                SECURITY_NETWORK_DREP,//SECURITY_NATIVE_DREP,
                fHaveCtxtHandle ? &InBuffer : NULL,
                0,
                fHaveCtxtHandle ? NULL : phContext ,
                &OutBuffer,
                &dwSSPIOutFlags,
                &tsExpiry
            );
```

### Can anyone help me with this? Thanks a lot. :)

---------------------------------------------------------------        edit           ---------------------------------------------------------------

```
    std::string fqdn = "HTTP/staging.company.com"; 
    char * server = new char[fqdn.size() + 1];
    std::copy(fqdn.begin(), fqdn.end(), server);
    server[fqdn.size()] = '\0';
```

So this is how I set up the Service name. I have this service name registered in my active directory as well. Though the address does not offer any particular service yet. Do you think that could be the problem? 
Another details: The Active directory is not in the same office, we tunnel to it via router.

Comment: What is the value you pass as the server? Is it a service principal name?

Comment: Hello @oldovets I have added the details in the question under edit section. Kindly have a look please

Comment: Ok, I created and assigned SPN to a user. Then tried to create context via REMSSPI (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/articles/ms973911(v=msdn.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN). Everything worked. Could you connect via this tool and check if it shows you the same error (JIT compiler will show the error code). Also, could you connect with the tool to any other SPN (e. g. any SPN assigned to a domain controller) to see if it's an SPN problem or not